# Setting up RAID during 22.04 installation

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, lvm

I have an Old Intel based Mac Pro with 4*4 TB hard drives. I am repurposing this machine to become an internal home file server running Ubuntu 22.04 Server. I couldn't find an option to setup a RAID during the installation. My end goal is to setup a RAID 1 or 5 or 6 on the four drives and then use this to create a LVM VG.

How can I accomplish this during installation? If that's not possible, how do I go about accomplish the above objective?

Comment: Will this array of 4 disks also be used for the root file system? Or is there a fifth storage device that will contain the OS so the 4 drives can be dedicated to file storage only?